# Replace Square Brackets with Curly Brackets

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a dataset like this (imported from .csv file):
`{[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]}`

I want to replace all square brackets with curly brackets like this:
`{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15}}`

I tried to make my dataset string and change to list again but it didn't work:

```
StringReplace["dataset", {"[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}]
If[SyntaxQ[#], ToExpression[#], #] & /@ StringSplit[a, ","]
```

I hope the question is clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that your file contains expression like this? In mathematica the syntax you quote is not consistent (unless it is a string)

Comment: Would this work? `"{[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]}" // 
   StringReplace[#, "[" -> "{"] & // 
  StringReplace[#, "]" -> "}"] & // ToExpression
`

Comment: Yes. The .csv file which i imported to Mathematica contains this expression.

Comment: Can you show us a subset of what is in the original file?

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. I solved problem. I opened .csv file and changed square brackets to curly brackets manually using CTRL+F...

Comment: `dataset = "{[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]}"; 
dataset // StringReplace[{"[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}] // ToExpression`

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. I opened .csv file and changed square brackets to curly brackets manually using CTRL+F...
Sometimes manual editing can be faster...